# Display image in view using asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, image, html-helper

I want to display image in view using asp.net mvc ?
I ham retrieved the image from database.

This is my view code :

```
    <td>
        <%: Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Product_img) %>
    </td>
```

But the Index page is like this :

[image]

How can I display the image?

Comment: How are you storing the image in the database and what datatype is the  `Product_img` field?  How are you retrieving the image from the database?

Comment: The _Product_img_ in database is image. I store it as a file (stream). I retrieve it as byte[].

Comment: It would seem you need to do some processing on the byte array to make it digestible as an image (see [here](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Display-Images-from-SQL-Server-Database-using-ASP.Net.aspx)).  Also, Depending on the size of the images you are storing, and their number, you may want to store them remotely (using [AWS S3](http://aws.amazon.com/s3/), for example) instead of in your database.

Comment: Maybe I have to make sth like this: <% HTML.Image(... to fetch byte array from db and display it as image. Right? But how??